# PHP DOMDocument suddenly object of different class

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to return the root element of a DOMDocument (`$doc->documentElement`) and then to access the public member `$foo` of the `ownerDocument`.
This gives me

```
Undefined property: DOMDocument::$foo in /var/www/temp/test.php on line 16
```

because after returning the root element the member `ownerDocument` is not any longer of class `\test\DOMDocument` but of `\DOMDocument`.

What's wrong with the code?

`(PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5123)`

```
<?php
namespace test;

class DOMDocument extends \DOMDocument {
    public $foo = 'bar';
}

function test() {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML('<root></root>');
    echo $doc->documentElement->ownerDocument->foo; // bar
    return $doc->documentElement;
}

$doc = test();
echo $doc->ownerDocument->foo; // error: $foo is not defined

?>
```

### The solution as proposed by ThW

```
<?php
namespace test;

class DOMDocument extends \DOMDocument {
    public $foo = 'bar';
}

function test($doc) {
    echo $doc->documentElement->ownerDocument->foo; // bar
    return $doc->documentElement;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root></root>');

$doc2 = test($doc);
echo $doc2->ownerDocument->foo; // bar

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the ext/dom GC. You always need a valid reference to your document object. If not the object can change its class to `\DOMDocument` or get removed from the memory completely.

You create the document inside the function and return only the document element node, not the document. The reference counter on $doc goes to zero at the end of the function call.

This will not affect you that much if you separate the create and the use of the document. You will have a variable with the document object in this case.